# how upload one file and 2 Query String param to spring service

Tags: java, android, retrofit, android-annotations

I could not like this

```
@Multipart
    @POST(API.URL.ME_UPLOAD_SINGLE)
    Observable<FileModule> postUploadSingle(@Part("fileData") RequestBody filePara,@QueryMap Map<String, String> map);
```

or

```
@Multipart
    @POST(API.URL.ME_UPLOAD_SINGLE)
    Observable<FileModule> postUploadSingle(@Part("fileData") RequestBody filePara, @Query("auth") String auth, @Query("token")String token);
```

I just want request the String params like Query to service.

Comment: Are you using the AndroidAnnotations library? (you added android-annotations tag)